# What is the name of words with two or more separate parts

Tags: grammar

In English language there are words like "the status quo", "per capita", "cul-de-sac" and so on. These words consists of two or more separate parts. I want to search for a list of such words, but I don't know what is the name of those.

Comment: They are sometimes called compound words or just compounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grammarly "compound words"](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/)
Two of the words you mention are called "open compound words" because they have spaces between their parts. There are also "closed" and "hyphenated" compounds, such as your third example.